# Lets chose just one image from two using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 4 images on the html site just two are visible . Thumbs Up and thumbs down. I have javascript code and i want the user can choose only one of the possibilities. If user click on thumbs up or down it get donker color. But my script lets allow user choose both possibilities.

[image]

i want this[image]

Html Code:

```
<body>
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="../Image/kleindownglow.jpg">
<img id="myImage2" onclick="changeImage2()" src="../Image/kleinupglow.png">
</body>
```

Script

```
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("glow")) {
        image.src = "../Image/kleindown.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "../Image/kleindownglow.jpg";
    }
}
function changeImage2() {
    var image2 = document.getElementById('myImage2');
    if (image2.src.match("upglow")) {
        image2.src = "../Image/kleinup.png";
    } else {
        image2.src = "../Image/kleinupglow.png";
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: No, i can't do that. I will search. Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
    <label for="test1">Red</label>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;    
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 2px;
  width: 24px; height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;

}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before
{
      background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeapplication/png/24x24/Bad%20mark.png'); 

}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before
{    
    background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/noshadow/standart/gif/24x24/001_18.gif') !important;
}
/* checked mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #09ad7e;
  transition: all .2s;

}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
/* disabled checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  color: #999;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  color: #aaa;
}
/* accessibility */
[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

/* hover style just for information */
label:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #4778d9!important;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    var checkedSt=$(this).prop('checked');
    alert(checkedSt ? "Like" : "UnLike");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/Ljvp74a5/)

### Indeterminate added

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/m49nmewg/)

Comment: Or how about you use a radio button! ;) Than the other becomes unchecked right away!

Comment: User is obliged to give its opinion ``;)``

Comment: @epascarello  Indeterminate added, see demo ``:)``.

Comment: @epascarello, radio button is very nice solution. The only thing that need to be implemented - you should be able to remove any selection at all (if you don't want neither to upvote nor downvote).

Comment: @Hamix, the user was asking for pure javascript solution according to the tags...

Comment: The person who did it, Like you think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's JSBin that solves your issue: http://jsbin.com/fiwadinosemi/1/edit

What it does:

1. If both are unselected and you press one of them - pressed item is glowed
2. If one item is glowed and you press it - it just removes glowing effect
3. If one item is glowes and you press other one - other one is glowed and old one is unglowed

So, this is normal behavior for up/downvote buttons

Comment: Probably because the code is not in your answer as the SO rules state.

Comment: @epascarello, strange, I've just reread the guide on how to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and it's not mentioned that my answer should contain any piece of code, but it's mentioned that it's good to use external links + describe them. So, I still don't know why it was downvoted. But according to the situation that all other answers are downvoted as well - looks like someone is just making a fun with this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make your code work, you would need to add a reference to the opposite image in your code and set that image to the unselected version.

If I were to do this, it would be pure CSS with a sprite and radio buttons.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="vote1" class="vote" id="down1" value="down" /><label for="down1"></label>
<input type="radio" name="vote1" class="vote" id="up1" value="up" /><label for="up1"></label>
<hr/>
<input type="radio" name="vote1" class="vote" id="down2" value="down" /><label for="down2"></label>
<input type="radio" name="vote1" class="vote" id="up2" value="up" /><label for="up2"></label>
```

**CSS:**

```
.vote { display: none; }

.vote + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width:55px; 
    height:65px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UauAa.png);
}

.vote[value="up"] + label {
    background-position: 55px 66px;
}
.vote[value="up"]:checked + label {
    background-position: 55px 0px;
}

.vote[value="down"] + label {
    background-position: 0px 66px;
}
.vote[value="down"]:checked + label {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

**Image:**

[image]
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UauAa.png)

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/coL4LhtL/

Comment: Flat line? That means what?

Comment: LOL, I did not use the OPs image and the line is probably some random border from their screen grab. And the only issue with this approach is if the OP wants the user to be able to unselect the option like you can do in the up/down here on SO.

Comment: @Hamix FYI, I did not downvote you. And I do not care about rep. Heck, watch as I upvote you. You are welcome. Enjoy your free 10 points. Also I did not steal your idea. Get off your pedestal. Your code is overly complicated with unnecessary selectors. That is the only reason I did not give you an upvote to start.

Comment: I'm an author, I think our problem is that our interests are similar.I'm Sorry.Good luck.